# how to set image programmatically in xCode

Tags: swift, xcode, uiimageview, uiimage

i have a little problem. I something tried, byt is is not correct. I have no idea, how to set image for every question. Can you help me, please? (i am beginner) thank you

[image]

---

my code is here:

```
class HardQuizViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var labelQuestion: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var buttonA: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var buttonB: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var buttonC: UIButton!

@IBOutlet var buttons: [UIButton]!

@IBOutlet weak var imageQuestion: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var tryAgainButton: UIButton!

var numberOfQuestion = -1
var score = 0

let questions = [
    HardQuestion(text: "What is it?", image: "pencil.jpg", correctAnswer: "pencil"),
    HardQuestion(text: "What is in the picture?", image: "apple.jpg", correctAnswer: "apple"),
    HardQuestion(text: "What animal is it?", image: "cat.jpg", correctAnswer: "cat")]

   let answers = [
       ["pencil","rubber","glue"],
       ["apple","pear","strawberry"],
       ["cat","dog","butterfly"]
       ].map { $0.shuffled()}

   @objc func updateUI(){
       if numberOfQuestion < questions.count - 1{
           numberOfQuestion += 1
       }
       labelQuestion.text = questions[numberOfQuestion].text


       //imageQuestion.image = UIImage(named: questions[numberOfQuestion].imageQuestion)

       buttonA.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
       buttonB.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
       buttonC.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear


       for (index, button) in buttons.enumerated() {
           button.setTitle(answers[numberOfQuestion][index], for: .normal)
       }

   }
```

Comment: You make an outlet to your image view and set the image view's `image`. And do not show _pictures_ of code; show _code_. It is text. Copy, paste, format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create an `@IBOutlet` by holding down control and click and drag from the storyboard to your view controller and it'll ask if you want to create an outlet release it there and you'll get a popup like this:

[image: Outlet]

Give a suitable name for your `UIImageView` and click connect and you'll find a new line added to your view controller like this:

```
@IBOutlet weak var imageQuestion: UIImageView!
```

Now you just need to set the image by calling

```
imageQuestion.image = UIImage(named: questions[numberOfQuestion].image)
```

Comment: i have an @IBOutlet named imageQuestion, but my problem is, that when i named for example "pencil.png", for every question will be the same image.

Comment: I think you're giving the wrong property name for the image name. Check the line I'm setting the image.